# Display git diff for unstaged and staged files in intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'd like to display in intellij the diff you can get with `git diff` (only unstaged changes) and `git diff HEAD` (all changes since last commit, staged or not), to have a color scheme when reviewing complex changes.

I use the git plugin but it seems to only display diffs between commits, or you have to check yourself file by file in the editor.

Did I miss an option?

Answer (score 2):

This should be described in "[Compare local changes with the repository version﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html#comparing_local_changes)"

> You can review changes in one of the following ways:
>
> - Preview changes in the `Local Changes` view : select a file and click Preview Diff preview details on the toolbar.
> - Explore changes in the [Differences Viewer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/differences-viewer.html): select a file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or click `show diff` on the toolbar.

Comment: Yes but every time it requires "select a file". I want a list of all modified files (and added for `git diff HEAD`) with their diff. Exactly like when you compare two commits by clicking on the `Git` bar, then select a commit and `show diff`.

Comment: But I don't see a way to compare a commit with local changes

Comment: @BaptisteMerliot OK. I am not aware of this particular feature being available.

Comment: Thanks for your help though, I guess I can still focus on complex files as you described and look at the rest with `git diff -- path/to/filter`